# Why is generic type not the correct type?

Tags: c#, generics

I have two classes, `BaseClass` and `Person`. The `Person` class inherits from `BaseClass`. I then use the following generic method.

```
    public static PropertyInfo GetProperty<T>(T item, Func<PropertyInfo, bool> predicate)
    {
        return GetProperty(typeof(T), predicate);
    }
```

Within the `BaseClass` I have a method, that invokes `GetProperty`

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var property = GetProperty(new Person(), (property) => p.Name == "Name");
    }
}
```

I then call this method from a unit test.

```
var person = new Person();
person.DoSomething();
```

When `typeof(T)` is used, `BaseClass` is returned. If I use `item.GetType()` then Person is returned. If I inspect them within the debugger, `T` is of type `BaseClass` and `item` is of type `Person`. Why does it not infer that `T` is a `typeof(Person)`, when it already knows that `item` is a Person?

### Edit

My example was wrong above sorry, when I call GetProperty, I pass `this`.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var property = GetProperty(this, (property) => p.Name == "Name");
    }
}
```

Comment: If the generic method was closed by the compiler with `T` = `BaseClass`, then the program will still compile and run and you would see exactly the output you are describing.  You should generally use `GetType()` when feasible as you will always get the concrete type of the object.

Comment: I don't know, but when I compile it, it correctly infers `Person`. Post it as a complete code.

Comment: In the scope of `BaseClass`, `typeof(this)` is always going to be `BaseClass`.  However, `this.GetType()` is overloaded and returns `Person`.

Comment: Ah ok, I was thinking `typeof(this)` would know that `this` was a child. Thanks

Comment: Now as you have updated the question, it is clear. In `DoSomething` you pass `this`, which is an object of type `BaseClass`. So the compiler correctly infers the type to be `BaseClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this inference problem is that generic inference happens at compile time, and is thus identical to specifying the desired type by hand. If you switch to explicitly stating `<Person>` with the call, does it throw an error during compile?

One way around this is to make sure that the variable (note: NOT the Object!) you pass in is explicitly of the `Person` class, as it seems to be in your code. Another way is to force generic inference to occur at runtime by using a [`dyanmic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) object thusly:

```
GetProperty(this as dynamic, (prop) => prop.Name == "Name");
```

By casting `this as dynamic` it calls `GetProperty<dynamic>` using the exact type of `this` at runtime. The problem with this approach is that dynamics are extremely slow compared to other objects.

If your models are strictly a single level of inheritance, you can also utilize Static Polymorphism to handle the generic parameter. Thusly:

```
public class BaseClass<TSelf> where TSelf : BaseClass<TSelf>

public sealed class Model : BaseClass<Model>
```

This way you could use `TSelf` as the parameter in place of `T` and it would be exactly correct. the problem with this approach is it strictly limits you to a flat single-inheritance hierarchy, as anything inheriting from `Model` would go back to the original problem and be seen as a `Model` because it can't override the generic parameter used by its base class.

Assuming your GetProperty function does some reflection to check for a property, you may want to consider passing a `Type` object in, instead of using a generic and then `typeof(T)`, as `.GetType()` is far more accurate.

Comment: The problem I have is that there are 30+ models that inherit from my base class and my view models call that base class method. Adding a strongly typed generic to the base-class method would be redundant. Your second suggestion I'm not sure I understand, would I supply that when invoking the method from my view model? `this.SelectedModel.DoSomething<dynamic>();` ?

Comment: To answer your question about explicitly stating `<Person>`, it does not throw an exception. In my unit tests, I have `PersonFixture : BaseClass` and I call `PersonFixture.DoSomething()`. When I debug, `typeof(T)` is `Person`

Comment: I edited my OP. I am passing `this` in to the method, and `this` with the invocation happening in the base class. Should I just pass `this.GetType()` when I invoke the method from within the base class?

Comment: To summarize the last paragraph of my updated answer, yes, you should do exactly that, but I've included a couple other options as well.

Comment: Thanks for the options, this will resolve my issue. Since this lives in a cache pool, I will probably leave the method signature and invocation by baseclass as is, and update the typeof(T) to use GetType(). I don't want to have users remember to always pass GetType() when using the cache :)